# Alternative gen interlock needed

Tags: electrical, generator

I’m installing a 60a sub panel in the garage to feed a car charger and serve as the tie point for a portable generator.  The garage is on the other end of the house so I only want to pay for 1 cable run, hence the subpanel. what residential interlocks are available to interlock the gen breaker in the garage sub panel to the main breaker in my main panel? All the interlock kits I see are for breakers in the same panel.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, we can help *A LOT* with the cost of wire.  Are you willing to let go of some wrong superstitions?

Comment: Have you already put the conduit in the ground?

Comment: Is the garage attached or detached?

Comment: "alternative" being a word for "not code compliant, no way, no how" here. Well, you can be code complaint if you only want the garage circuits to run from the generator. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/37031/18078

Comment: I added an answer to the other question.  Upshot: lose any superstitions about aluminum wire... and *voila*, costs fall right into line.