Is the power inlet near a hot tub outlet usable as it is?
I have a subpanel outside located where a hot tub once was. The hot tub was on a 60 amp breaker in the subpanel, then ran to the main panel (interlock installed) to another 60 amp breaker. There was also a 30 amp inlet directly next to and ran to the subpanel on a 30 amp DP breaker, for what I'm guessing was a generator hookup.(Hot tub is gone so the only thing that would be used is the Inlet). Is this usable, or was this just not installed correctly? I have a generator but have never used the inlet.

Size of generator in watts?  The 30 amp inlet was probably for a generator of up to ~7000 watts.  Changing the inlet/breaker, you might get a generator of up to ~14000 watts, if the wires were sized right for 60 amps.

Not exactly a duplicate, since asking if it's OK or wrong is different from "I'm planning to do this thing" in my view... https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/37030/18078 also, here the hot tub is "former."

I currently have a 5500W 8200w start generator and it was wired with 6awg

That's usable, as described in the 4th paragraph of this answer.
You can't put an inlet on a sub-panel unless the only things you want to power from the inlet are on that sub-panel - or the things on that sub-panel are only powered by the generator, and never by utility power - at least not safely, legally, and in a way that won't cause the power company to perhaps give you an extra long outage by disconnecting your house until it's corrected and inspected.
They don't like people that put linemen in danger.
You didn't initally describe there being an interlock here, or at the main panel. You have now edited that there is one at the main panel.  Since there is an interlock kit at the main panel, it can work as a proper, safe, code-compliant inlet by interlocking at the main panel. If you added anything to the subpanel where the hot-tub has been removed, it could only be powered by the generator, but you're not planning to do that.
An interlock is a device that permits two breakers (the main and the generator inlet) to both be off, while permitting only one of them to be on.

Currently the only thing on the sub-panel is the 30amp inlet...the Hot tub was removed shortly after we purchased the house. So, they have the inlet going to sub-panel on a 30amp DP breaker, then to the main panel on a 60 DP

And the main panel has a interlock switch

Well, that makes all the difference. Please edit it into your question.
