Is it possible to piggyback off a 50 amp spa box to install a 30 amp generator inlet box
I’m trying to install a 30amp generator inlet box and currently have a 50amp spa box in the same general area I wish to install the inlet box. Is it possible to piggyback/daisy chain from the spa box to the inlet box? Thanks in advance for the guidance.


A picture of the spa box will help.  With it being bigger than 30 amps is a plus.  You will want a way to disconnect/not power the spa from the generator and need an interlock at the panel.

Only if you want the spa to be the only thing the generator powers. Duplicate, I'll go find them in a second. If you don't plan to use the spa ever again, or only on generator power: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/297854/18078 If that's not what you are doing: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/37031/18078

You're not  planning on directly feeding your main panel from this are you?

If the spa panel is fed by conduit you could add wires back to the service if the conduit has capacity, but no way to use the same wire to a functioning spa box.

Crip659 Sorry, I didn’t realize the photo didn’t load. I’ve added a pic of the spa box.

The interlock would still go on the sub panel which unfortunately, is upstairs in our laundry room in the middle of the house. That’s the main issue. I don’t see a way for me to fish the wiring from the panel to the exterior of the house.

Jack Just looking for options and have been told this was possible but want to get input from other with with far more knowledge.

If the laundry room is a tough fish, what about the main panel?  Forget the spa, can you get a cable from a suitable outside location to the main panel?
